# Compare unsorted arrays in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, filter, google-sheets, transpose, google-sheets-formula

In cell A1 I have `{UK,GERMANY,US}`
In cell B1 I have `{US,UK,FRANCE,ITALY,THE NETHERLANDS}`
I would like to use a formula to return in cell C1 `{FRANCE,ITALY,THE NETHERLANDS}`
That is all elements present in array2 that are not available in array1.

All elements are unsorted, separated by a comma, may contain a space.

I have been looking all night at formulas to compare text array elements but I can’t find what I am looking for.

Can you help me out?

I actually am using Google Sheet, connected to a Google Form in which there are 2 questions. A short open questions, in which I expect to receive bits of codes that identify an objects (I expect more than one, one after the other, like `{1234 8888 9999 3334}`) and a multiple selection questions in which I can I expect to receive Country names like `{US,UK,FRANCE,ITALY,THE NETHERLANDS}`.

In another sheet, I have a list of codes, one per row (e.g. 1234) and Countries associated with that code (e.g. `{UK,GERMANY,US}`). That's where I want to highlight differences vs/ the form answers.

At the moment I managed to create the formula to search all Countries in the form answer sheet for a given object, even on multiple rows, and retrieve them next to the group of Countries I need to compare them against.

Now I "just" need to search `{US,UK,FRANCE,ITALY,THE NETHERLANDS}` individually in `{UK,GERMANY,US}` to highlight the differences, that is `{FRANCE,ITALY,THE NETHERLANDS}`.

In my B1 cell formula, I have

```
=substitute(textjoin(", ",TRUE,arrayformula(FILTER('Answerform'!CountryColumn,ISNUMBER(Search(ObjectCodeCell,'Answerform'!MultipleObjectColumn))))),", ",",")
```

(note: Google form feedback is with spaces after a comma, I thought I needed to eliminate them to compare them with elements that don't have space after the comma - that is why there's a substitute)

I expect the output to be `{FRANCE,ITALY,THE NETHERLANDS}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
="{"&TRIM(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, 
 FILTER(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(B1, "{|}", ), ",")), NOT(COUNTIF(
        TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1, "{|}", ), ",")), 
        TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(B1, "{|}", ), ",")))))))&"}"
```

[image: 0]

Comment: SPOT ON! This works like a treat, thanks!Now I shall study the logic behind it, as I have no idea what's going on in your formula.